# Render to textue array with ATI hardware

Tags: opengl, 3d, ati

I have an OpenGL implementation that supposedly should make it possible to render to a texture array. This by selecting different layers in the geometry shader. Though, the problem is that this does not work due to a ATI driver bug. I would really like to get this working, and I have come up with a couple of alternatives, on how to proceed:

1. Remake the implementation in Direct3D, are ATI drivers better at D3D?
2. Come up with a workaround (cant think of any though).
3. Buy an nVidia card.

What should I do? Any other alternatives?

Comment: D3d drivers are in general less buggy AFAIK. But if you are only using this for yourself then buying a Nvidia card instead will save you the time reimplementing it.

Comment: If you really want to do OpenGL stuff, buying a nVidia card will definitely spare you much pain. AMD should stay with its CPUs and keep their hands off graphics cards.

Answer (score 1):

This is an outdated way, but it should work on ATI cards. This renders the depthmap to a texture, but you can render pretty much anything.

```
// generate texture (in init method)
init(){...
glGenTextures(1, &depthTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 512,
512, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,GL_FLOAT, 0);}

// draw the mesh to fill the depth buffer
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
draw_mesh();
// copy depth buffer to texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture);
glCopyTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 512, 512);
// clear screen
cls();
// enable texturing and bind the depth texture
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture);
// overlay texture to fullsizequad
drawFullsizeQuad();
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider filing a bug to ATI: your test case (layered rendering) is supposed to be small and 100% reproducable.